# Find $\sin(A)$ and $p(x)$ such that $p(A)=\sin(A)$

Tags: matrices

Given 
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\pi}{2} & 1 & 2 \\
0 & \pi & 3 \\
0 & 0 & -\pi
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\text{find}
 \sin(A)
$$
$$
\text{I have found the spectral decomposition of A to be}
$$
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}E_1 + \pi E_2 - \pi E_3
$$
with
$$
E_{1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\pi & \frac{4\pi -12}{3 \pi^{2}}\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
E_{2}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{2}{\pi} & \frac{3}{\pi^{2}}\\
0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2\pi}\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
E_{3}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac{3-4\pi}{3\pi^{2}}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{-3}{2\pi}\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I then used this to say
$$
\sin(A)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)E_{1} + \sin(\pi)E_{2} - \sin(\pi)E_{3}
\therefore \sin(A)=E_1
$$
I now need to find $p(x)$ such that $p(A)=\sin(A)$.

Comment: How did you find these $E_1,E_2,E_3$? and how could you split up $\sin A$ using them?

Comment: You don't need to write \operatorname{sin}; just \sin is enough.  It's a standard operator name in $\TeX$.

Comment: Do you intend $p$ to be a polynomial?  If there are no constraints on what $p$ can be, why not just say $p=\sin$ and you're done?  Also $p$ could be the usual power-series expansion of the sine function.

Comment: @MichaelHardy p needs to be a polynomial.

Comment: @Berci the E's are found using the lagrange interpolation polynomials, $$E_{1}=\lambda_{1}h_{1}(A)$$.  There is an example in my text book (Matrices and Linear Transfromations, Cullen) that found sin(A) by that method, so I followed that.  However, I don't know how to get the p(x).  I know the answer for p(x) because it is in the back of the book, but I don't know how to get it.  However, the book does not give me sin(A).

Comment: Find the degree 2 polynomial that agrees with $\sin$ on the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @copper.hat I have found a "lagrange interpolation formula" in my textbook.  It says $$ p(x)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}p(\lambda_{i})h_{i}(x)$$ I used this with my working above and I got $$ \frac{4}{3}-\frac{4}{3\pi^{2}}x^{2}$$  could the textbook perhaps have a typo in it?

Comment: @sarahjamal: Yes, if the answer you gave below is what the textbook gave, then it is wrong. Your answer is correct, to check, note that $p(-\pi) = p(\pi) = 0$, $p(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1$. You could also check by just evaluating $p(A)$.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks so much!! now I have another matrix $$ J_{3}(\frac{\pi}{2}) $$ and I need to find $$\sin(J) \text{ and } \cos(J)$$  however, since I only have one eigenvalue, I don't know how to use the spectral decomposition method. :(

Comment: If $d$ is the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ (ie, the size of the largest Jordan block), then you need $p^{(k)}(\lambda) = f^{(k)}(\lambda)$ for all $k=0,...,d-1$, where $f$ is the function in question. In your example above, $d=1$ for all eigenvalues, so there was no need to match derivatives. Alternatively, you could try computing the matrices directly (ie, using the power series expansion) once you have figured out a formula for $J^k$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that your 'spectral decomposition' is good.

However, you can reduct the problem to the case for $A':=\begin{bmatrix} \pi/2 &0&0 \\ 0&\pi&0 \\ 0&0&-\pi \end{bmatrix}$.

This is because $A$ has 3 different eigenvalues, and take one eigenvector for each: $v_1,v_2,v_3$, it is a basis, then the matrix $B:=\left[ v_1|v_2|v_3 \right]$ is invertible and it will conjugate $A$ to $A'$:
$$A=BA'B^{-1}$$
With this, using $(BAB^{-1})^n = BA^nB^{-1}$, we get that both
$$p(A)=B\cdot p(A')\cdot B^{-1}\ \text{ and }\ \sin(A) = B\cdot \sin(A')\cdot B^{-1} $$
(because $\sin$ is defined by its power series..)

So, $p(A)=\sin(A) \iff p(A')=\sin(A')$.

Comment: And $\sin(A')=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Berci the textbook gives me $$ p(x)=\frac{4}{3}-(\frac{4}{3}\pi{^2})x^{2}$$

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: I haven't calculated the polynom, this might be good, we can verify if $p(A')=\sin(A')$. Ah, I see, a typo, yes, the $\pi^2$ should go in the *denominator*, and then it seems to work.